# Upgrading Postgres Aurora Major Version

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

According to:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.Upgrading.html

> Manually Upgrading the Engine Version
>
> To perform a major version upgrade of a DB cluster, you can restore a
>   snapshot of the DB cluster and specify a higher major engine version.
>   For information about restoring a DB cluster, see Restoring from a DB
>   Cluster Snapshot.

Yet I don't see anywhere the option of choosing a database engine at restore.
Is the documentation incorrect?
Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also encountered the same issue when attempting to upgrade Aurora Postgres from 9.x to 10.x.  The GUI and aws-cli does not allow you to specify a higher version number when restoring a snapshot.

AWS support confirms this is NOT supported at this time, this from my chat session with the tech:

> I should have recollected earlier. Currently there isn't an in-place upgrade path from Aurora 9.x to version 10.
>   This is something that is frequently requested for and the engineering team is working on but we don't have an ETA as to when this will be fixed.

AWS did offer two options:

1. Use pg_dump and pg_restore to extract and load the data into an    upgrade target cluster.
2. Use AWS Data Migration Services to migrate data. DMS has the advantage of minimal downtime but it comes with many limitations you would have to evaluate. For example some data types, like JSON and timestamps with time zones are 'partially migrated'.

Links to AWS DMS documentation using PostgreSQL as a source and/or target of DMS:

Postgres as DMS Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html#CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.Homogeneous.DMS

Postgres as DMS Target:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.PostgreSQL.html

The tech I chatted with favored pg_dump/pg_restore because it's more native, but it involve more downtime.

Comment: I think that DMS is supported only for MysQL Aurora. (Not postgres)

Comment: Actually PostgreSQL is supported as **both a source and target of DMS**, see the links for more documentation:

[Postgres as DMS Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html#CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.Homogeneous.DMS) **and** [Postgres as DMS Target](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.PostgreSQL.html)

The AWS tech I spoke with was the one who suggested DMS is an option for our Aurora PostgreSQL data migration.

Comment: It seems you're right: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.html Until few months ago this was not the case.

Comment: @Spiff What do I need to add to make this the accepted answer?

Comment: This is now supported by Aurora. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.PostgreSQL.html

Answer (score 4):

This is now supported by Aurora Postgres. There is no need to restore a snapshot into a new cluster anymore. The procedure is explained [in the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.PostgreSQL.html).

As of 2020/05/22: 
"Currently, you can do a major version upgrade from Aurora PostgreSQL version 9.6.11 or 9.6.12 database clusters to Aurora PostgreSQL version 10.11."